# How do I handle my user-specified exception in my test case

Tags: java, arraylist, exception, throws

I previously wrote an entire successful program composed of 7 classes(`Date`, `Address`, `Time`, `Customer`, `Course`, `InClassCourse`, `OnLineCourse`), an interface (`Invoice`) and of course the test class (`CustomerTest`). The interface `Invoice` has a method `createInvoice` which is implemented in the `Customer` class. In the test case, I created 3 new customers, added their respective courses, and then calculated their charges depending on the numbers of courses they are enrolled in, the type of course they are enrolled in and whether the class is an `InClassCourse` or `OnLineCourse`, and finally print out the information a dialogue box. The list of customers and courses are kept in two separate array lists:

```
ArrayList<Customer> customerList = new ArrayList<Customer>();
ArrayList<Course> courseList = new ArrayList<Course>();
```

Using an enhanced for loop, I polymorphically walked through the `customerList` and created the invoice for each customer.
I have now written an additional class `CreateFiles`, containing a new list of customers and courses, that writes customer data to a file **customers.txt** and course data to file **courses.txt**. `CreateFiles` has a method `writeCustomers` and `writeCourses`.

I am new to exceptions and still learning. To modify my program I would like to add a user-specified exception called `CustomerNotEnrolledException`. The `createInvoice` method in the `Customer` class will throw `CustomerNotEnrolledException` if the customer does not have any courses on his list (several of my customers are not enrolled in any courses), and then handle this exception in my test class.

**My question is how do I handle my exception in the main if a customer is NOT enrolled in any courses, that is, how do I write the try block.** I need to do this because after I have eliminate the non-enrolled customers, I will add methods `readCustomers`, `readCourses`, and `generateInvoice` in the Test case and use them to read the **customers.txt** file and **courses.txt** file to create customers and add them to `customerList`, as well as, create courses, which would be added to their respective customers.

I already created an exception class called CustomerNotEnrolledException that extends exception:

```
  public class CustomerNotEnrolledException extends Exception
  {
      public CustomerNotEnrolledException()
      {
         super("Customer not enrolled");
      }
```

createInvoice method looks like this:

```
    public String createInvoice() throws CustomerNotEnrolledException
    {      
         if((courseList == null) || (this.courseList.isEmpty()))
        {
            throw new CustomerNotEnrolledException();
        }                 
         double total;

        if (cType==CustomerType.STUDENT)
            total = 25;
               else if (cType==CustomerType.FACULTY)
            total = 50;
               else if (cType==CustomerType.GOVERNMENT)
            total = 35;
        else
            total = 0;

       for(Course course:this.courseList)
       {
           total += course.calculateCharge(this.cType); 
       }  

           return (String.format("%s\t\t%d\t\t$%.2f", this.name,      
               this.accountNumber,total));    
    }
```

Comment: Please formulate your exact question.

Comment: How to I write the code to check for my exception, Im guessing it will be in the try block?

Comment: You do not *check* for exception. You `throw` it where applicable and then `try` to `catch`.

Comment: Work through [`Exceptions Tutorial`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/index.html) first.

Comment: This is a custom exception that **you** created. So now **you** have to decide how your code should react when it's thrown.